# How to insert Chinese characters in rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, encoding

I was trying to insert a string of Chinese characters into database via rails console. It seems that rails ignored all the Chinese characters and only inserted English characters. How do I fix this?

Comment: Including sample code might make it easy for answering.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's difficult to tell what you're trying to do based on the little information you gave us. *How* are you trying to insert the characters, using what steps? What database manager? How did you set up the database? How are you checking to see if the characters were inserted? Were any errors generated? A good way to tell if your question is going to be understandable is to reread it and see if YOU would need additional information to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you are giving away not too much information, it is most likely an issue with he charset of a particular attribute or table of your database.

For example if you are trying to save the name of a person and the attribute 'name' in your database table is formatted to charset "latin1" the Chinese characters get lost. Make sure all attributes are formatted to i.e.: "utf8".

Hope that resolves the issue. Here a bit more information on choosing the right character set: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/oracle8/server.815/a67789/ch3.htm